# How to apply require field validation for a group of Dynamic radio button

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, radio-button, customvalidator

I am creating a group of radio button dynamically inside a asp:table control.

eg: 
Qst1

rb1
rb2
rb2

Qyst2

rb1
rb2
rb2

Need:

User should select answer for each question. I planed to use custom validator for this. Please any one guide me on this

code:

```
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();

        radioButton.ID = id;
        radioButton.ToolTip = text;
        radioButton.Attributes.Add(ID_TEXT, id);
        radioButton.GroupName = categoryID + QUESTIONS;
        radioButton.EnableViewState = true;
        radioButton.AutoPostBack = false;
        radioButton.Checked = isSelected;

        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(radioButton);

        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        row.Height = 20;
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Update:

I got solution by using Custome validator:

Code:

```
protected void ValidateSample(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
        string rbGroupName = string.Empty;
        bool valid = false;
        bool groupSelection = false;

        foreach (TableRow tr in QuestionTable.Controls)
        {

            foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Controls)
            {
                if (tc.Controls[0] is Label)
                {
                    if (QuestionTable.Rows.GetRowIndex(tr) + 1 <= QuestionTable.Rows.Count)
                    {
                        rb = (RadioButton)
                            QuestionTable.Rows[QuestionTable.Rows.GetRowIndex(tr) + 1]
                            .Cells[0].Controls[0];
                        if (rb != null)
                        {
                            rbGroupName = rb.GroupName;
                            valid = groupSelection;
                            groupSelection = false;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }

                if (tc.Controls[0] is RadioButton)
                {
                    rb = (RadioButton)tc.Controls[0];
                    if (rb.GroupName.Equals(rbGroupName))
                    {
                        if (rb.Checked)
                        {
                            groupSelection = true;
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        args.IsValid = valid;
    }

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" class="LabelErrorStyle" Text="*" ErrorMessage="Please select one of the radio button" OnServerValidate="ValidateSample" ValidateEmptyText="true"
Display="Dynamic" >*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Why not use a `RadioButton List` and then create a required field validator and attach it also in the code

Comment: If i use radiobuttonlist it will not meets the client design

Comment: I think you should try JQuery validation on submit click and pass the groupnames to the function which will validate the controls

Answer (score 0):

You can add validation dynamically by following ways , you have to make sure about different validation as per radiobutton group

```
 RequiredFieldValidator rqdVal = new RequiredFieldValidator(); 
    rqdVal.ID = "rqdVal" + i.ToString(); 
    rqdVal.ControlToValidate = "id"; 
    rqdVal.ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value"; 
    rqdVal.Display =ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
```

for more info please look at [this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1682411.aspx/1)

Comment: Are you sure this would work for the `radiobutton` which is n question above ?

Comment: For each group of radiobutton i need a require field validator